# Blender texture baking fail

Tags: texture-baking

I'm new to blender so please bear in mind that I might be stupid with this. But I am making my first object in blender which is a cookie, and I am trying to bake the texture of it into an image, but it doesn't bake the whole texture, only two small parts of the objects colors. I have tried looking up a similar problem but I can't find anyone with the same. Also there is no preview of the object in the image before baking, so I can not see what is supposed to show a cookie, it's just black. I attached a photo of how it looks once it's baked. What I did was, as I've learned, to select the object in object mode, switch into edit mode and bake the texture into a new image. When I look at other people doing the exact same thing they do not have this problem. Please help!

You can download the blend file here if you want to look at it:
https://mega.nz/#!5iJnyLIS!vIOr2gj1Tjh6ikJEfuPeiKTM5YakuR5nZsKJbOKINNM

Regards,
Becca

After finished texture is applied:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to check Selected to Active in Bake properties (Image below). Second, you need to have the plane, on which you want to bake the cookie UV unwrapped (go to edit mode,open UV/Image Editor window, select the texture on which you want the cookie to be baked, press U and choose Unwrap). You also need the plane to be in front of the part of the cookie, that you need to be visible. So in this case, on top/in front instead of bottom/back. Then you need to make sure, that in Distance property you have appropriate number. Looking on your scene, I think that 1-2 would be enough. Next, in object mode, you need to select cookie, then Shift select the plane and press Bake.That should do the job.Also if you need to bake only color, without shadows and lights, choose Textures in Bake Mode.

[image]

Here you have shown step by step, what you need to do
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it all and it still does the same thing. I also tried the whole process in a new blender file with a simple sphere and that works fine. Which leads me to believe the cookie is somewhat wrongly created? I attached a download link to the blender file in the topic so that you can try it yourself if you want, maybe you'll see a problem I can't see with my cookie. Thanks

Comment: The cookie is fine. The plane however is wrong. First of all you need to apply scale, then unwrap it, remove material from it, cause it's interfering with the bake. I added step by step .gif, what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see if I can keep up with the gif. By the way, the plane in my blend file is actually a plane from another object (a shelf), which I've hidden, I just hadn't done anything about the plane of it. So I understand why it could be wrong, I just thought it wouldn't matter much what the plane was like as long as there at least was one, but I guess I learned something new then :)

Comment: I followed your gif and it worked! I have no idea what the exact purpose of every step was, since I'm new to this, but I guess in time I'll understand it. So I now have the texture baked. The only problem I have now is that when I open the blender file in the Sims4Studio program, which I use to create new objects for The sims 4, the texture doesn't fit the cookie, but rather keeps repeating itself. Any idea what that could be about? is the texture image too small or something? Thanks for your effort and help!

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with Sims4Studio so can't help you there. Good luck though. I'm sure someone will.